# Dead-end / Spam questions from new users

Tags: discussion, questions, new-users, spam

**Please see this question: [What's wrong in this iban validation code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2582022/whats-wrong-in-this-iban-validation-code)**

I think this kind of thing will start to hurt Stack Overflow.

Because the original question contained a spammy link and the User's rep is essentially 0, I'm guessing either the question is not real and is just a vessel for the spam link, and the OP has no intentions of coming back to provide more information for answering this.

Over time, will Stack Overflow be cluttered with a bunch of dead-end questions? What happens to these?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the edit history, you can see that a user edited out the spammy link within 10 minutes of the original post. Given what the original post contained, I think the link is more likely just a signature than a direct attempt at spam.

Regardless, the system works, whether or not the question actually contains a real question.

If a question is truly unworthy of being answered (and the one linked to seems to be heading in that general direction), it will first be closed, and then deleted.

If a question is actual spam and gets *flagged as spam*, I believe the post can be automatically deleted by the system (someone comment on how many flags it takes? 6?).

Comment: If this isn't outdated, it takes 6 flags: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/raising-a-red-flag/

Comment: The info *should* be in the FAQ, but it's either not there or very unclear: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16327/how-do-you-report-a-spammer-on-so

Comment: It isn't mentioned directly - that answers don't really look like FAQ material to me anyway.

Answer (score 1):

How could you tell questions from new users that didn't bother to look for the signature rules from well disguised spam questions?
Some new users simply keep their signature behavior from other sites, but others users will (hopefully) tell them that signatures are not welcome on SO.

The question doesn't actually contain a real question, but doesn't look like spam to me.
Also, please give new users the benefit of doubt and explain to them what they are doing wrong instead of accusing them right away.

Answer (score 0):

I have to believe that this user genuinely has a problem with his code, link or not. I'm guessing he's treating SO like any other web forum -- notice that there were greets and a sign-off there as well. (I just edited those out.)

I'm not seeing ill intent here, just an ill-formed question with a signature, said signature just *happened* to contain a link.

You'll know it's spammy if multiple users start posting an identical link in this way. Or if one user keeps doing it after it continuously gets edited out. (And that can possibly be rectified by flagging the post for mod review; the mod may be able to e-mail the user and explain the greets/signature rules.)